# Material design lite checkbox do not render properly

Tags: angular, material-design, material-design-lite

In my index.html fie I have:

```
  <!-- Material Design Lite -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.teal-red.min.css" />
  <script src="/bower_components/material-design-lite/material.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Material Design icon font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

And for checkbox I have following code:

```
<div class="demo-checkbox myCheck">
                <h5>You have choosen so far</h5>
                <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
                    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hasHall" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
                    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Marriage Hall</span> 
                </label>

                <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
                    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hasCaterer" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
                    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Caterer</span>
                </label>
                <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
                    <input type="checkbox"  class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
                    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Decorator</span>
                </label>
            </div>
```

This however renders checkboxes like following:

[image]

Why is it so? Buttons and other components **are** rendered correctly, it's only with checkbox that I face this issue.

Comment: Did you see any error? Perhaps console error like 404 not found file?

Comment: No there is no such error!

Answer (score 0):

I put this into jsfiddle, and by adding the material design js library, the checkboxes render correctly, it maybe how you are referencing your js, try this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No  unfortunately it didn't! I tried even changing order of my css files, but didn't help.

Comment: I have removed your local js and css settings, so something is perhaps overring?

Comment: Yes something is overriding, that is correct. I am not able to figure out what! I checked your fiidle, it looks perfect but same settings wouldn't work on my local.

Comment: start with the basic working file as per the fiddle, then add each js/css file in individually to see which file is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't any problem with default javascripts overriding mdl. I got a workaround like following:

In my respective x.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var componentHandler: any;

ngOnInit() {
    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
}
```

This solved the rendering issue